# Launch Storyboard not found - Xcode 10 uploading to app store

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, launch-screen

I'm getting the error 'Launch Storyboard not found' in Xcode 10 when trying to upload the Archive to TestFlight.

I added LaunchScreen to the Info Plist and added it directly to the main project folder.

One thing I noticed is that the main Target of the storyboard is greyed out so I can't check it, though.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it linking by adding the file to Compile Sources.

It seems that if when bundling using react-native (I also used ignite as a starting boilerplate) it wouldn't let me link up the target, even manually -- so adding it to here did the trick and thus I was able to archive the project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just create new storyboard => right click on the project => New File => Choose story board ( name it as Launch or anything ). Storyboard name can be anything.

[image]

[image]

In case LaunchScreen not display then remove and add again.

[image]

Comment: I added LaunchScreen.storyboard by using Add New File to the same folder where main.m/Info Plist is. It doesn't automatically pull into the 'Launch Screen File' option, though. Doesn't seem to be recognizing it.

Comment: @MaxNachamkin select target membership  checked. And remove spacing between Launch and Screen, do like this LaunchScreen

Comment: that's the thing. I can't check Target Membership -- it's grayed out.

Comment: @MaxNachamkin can you try out to remove this and create new file?

Comment: When you try to create new one ,  then you can able to check your project targets?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188799/discussion-between-mitesh-jadav-and-max-nachamkin).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Launch Screen` to the `General > App Icons and Launch Screen`

[image]

Whilst your Storyboard is open, ensure you've selected it as an Initial View Controller.

[image]